# What does the black book with a red pentagram do?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I was on a run and entered a devil room, for 2 red hearts was a black book with a pentagram on it. 
I didn't want to sacrifice the 2 hearts for an item I didn't need or possibly didn't want.

Does anyone know what it does?

Answer (score 2):

Its the satanic bible, on usage, gives you a black heart

Answer (score 2):

If you mean this one:

[image]

it's the **Satanic Bible**, and gives Isaac a black heart when used. A behaviour similar to the Book of revelations.

It's an evil item, so probably it increases the chance of spawning a devil deal room.

Source [here](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Satanic_Bible).

Comment: That ain't no red pentagram in (on) my book.

Comment: Your comment means no sense to me, because the OP says "was a black book with a pentagram on it". I don't read anything about red pentagrams.

Comment: Question title does, though. But I see your point.

Comment: You're right, I'll change my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two books with pentagrams in the game.

If the book has a *black* pentagram on it, it is the **Book of Belial**. It's a 3-room charge, and gives you +2 damage for your current room. It also has the nice bonus of giving you a 100% Devil/Angel room chance, and all Devil/Angel rooms stay open forever.

If the book has a *red* pentagram on it, it is the **Satanic Bible**. It's a 6-room charge, and gives you one black heart on use.

[This website](http://platinumgod.co.uk/) may be helpful for you in the future.